# Need to update second table with insert or update to primary table

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have two tables : **a**,**b** and I have written down stored procedure for insert and deletion of record from table b.

I am trying to use a trigger on table **a** with the following code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterUpdate 
ON [dbo].[Inventory]
FOR UPDATE
AS
    EXEC dbo.usp_open_update_generateorder
GO
```

But this doesn't seem to work. There is nothing wrong with the sp as when executed separately it is working fine.

Comment: what is the definition of `dbo.usp_open_update_generateorder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `FOR UPDATE` try `AFTER INSERT, UPDATE`